# How to initialize values in c

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I started learning C using learncodethehardway book. There is an [exercise](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html) 
where its talking about valgrind. And at the end it asks to "fix" the valgrind errors. the program is pretty simple,but whatever I tried, valgrind throws

```
Use of uninitialised value of size
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

I looked for it online, but couldn't find any solution related. I used malloc to initialize memory, but that didn't work either. Any pointers would be very helpful.

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main( int c, char *argv[]){

    int age = malloc(sizeof(int));
    age = 12;
    int height = 12;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n",age);
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n",height);

    return 0;
}
```

Based on solutions provided below, I updated the code, 
UPDATED Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main( int c, char **argv[]){

    int* age = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *age = 12;
    int* height = malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
    *height = 23;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n",age);
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n",height);

    free(age);
    free(height);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
   ==19385== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19385== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19385== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19385== Command: ./ex4
==19385== 
I am -16775192 years old.
==19385== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==19385==    at 0x4E71EBB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==19385==    by 0x4E73E96: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1622)
==19385==    by 0x4E7D169: printf (printf.c:35)
==19385==    by 0x40053D: main (ex4.c:9)
==19385== 
==19385== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19385==    at 0x4E71EC5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==19385==    by 0x4E73E96: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1622)
==19385==    by 0x4E7D169: printf (printf.c:35)
==19385==    by 0x40053D: main (ex4.c:9)
==19385== 
==19385== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19385==    at 0x4E73FAA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1622)
==19385==    by 0x4E7D169: printf (printf.c:35)
==19385==    by 0x40053D: main (ex4.c:9)
==19385== 
==19385== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19385==    at 0x4E73FC8: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1622)
==19385==    by 0x4E7D169: printf (printf.c:35)
==19385==    by 0x40053D: main (ex4.c:9)
==19385== 
I am 0 inches tall.
==19385== 
==19385== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19385==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19385==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==19385== 
==19385== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19385== 
==19385== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19385== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==19385== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: If you include `stdlib` and compile with `-Wall` [you should get the warnings](http://ideone.com/IPOfqE) and you won't even need the valgrind. `int *argv[]` ha ha

Comment: I do have -Wall in make file, but as I said, I am working on the book exercises, so its not something that is not a solution for I ask, the book asked to understand the valgrind errors, i am trying to do that. thanks

Comment: Use of `malloc` in your code is incorrect. Use just `int main(void)`. The only takeaway from the exercise is: **Always initialize the variable before accessing them**. It is height in your case.

Comment: @MohitJain I tried your suggestions, still it didn't work.

Comment: I ran your program, and valgrind [doesn't report any error](http://ideone.com/kZBlYt). Are you sure you are compiling correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `malloc` function is used to allocate memory on the heap, and it returns a *pointer* to the memory. Therefore, `age` should not be an `int`, it should be a pointer to an int, or `int*`:

```
int* age = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Then, you need to assign to the location *referenced by* `age`, so you need to dereference `age` using the `*` operator:

```
*age = 12;
```

Though it doesn't matter for such a simple program, you should also free all memory allocated on the heap before your program terminates to avoid memory leaks (though when you program quits, all memory will be automatically freed by the operating system).

Just place the following line just before the `return` statement:

```
free(age);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int *age = malloc(sizeof(int));

*age = 12;
```

`age` should be a pointer if you want to allocate memory and store the return value of `malloc()` then dereference the pointer to store the value .

If age is just a variable then do

```
int age = 12;
```

free the memory after used using

```
free(age);
```

once you are done using this memory

Answer (score -1):

- Code didn't include stdlib.h.
- The form of main is incorrect.
- `age` needs to be a pointer.
- You need to check the result of malloc.
- You need to free() allocated memory.

Comment: I did all that u said in the updated code, but it still gives the error.